# Limit of function formed by taking difference after swapping a variable / constant

Tags: limits

How to apply L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate limit at $x=a$ for

$$ \frac {f(x,a)-f(a,x)}{(x-a)}  \tag{1} $$

which has $\frac00$ form? If it cannot be applied, how is the limit found?

EDIT1:

[image: x^e-e^x]

The blue and purple plots are for curves:
$$ y=\dfrac{ x^e - e^x}{ x - e}; \,  y=  (x^e - e^x)  $$
respectively for the limit and the numerator, which are *both vanishing* at $x=e.$

EDIT2

If $ f(x,a) = a \sin x$ or $x \sin a, $ then such a limit is $ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,a)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,a)= a \cos a - \sin a, $

If $ f(x,a) = a ^x $ or $x^a$ ,then such a limit is $ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,a)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,a)= a^a (\log a-1). $

EDIT3:

So we can *define* for two variables an order independent *Swap derivative* for (1) as

$$ SDf(x,a) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,a)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,a). $$

We have for two example functions  $$ f(x,a) = a \sin x,\;  x^a  $$

their corresponding SD's:

$$a \cos a - \sin a, \, a^a (\log a-1). $$

Comment: The first function is not defined for $x=e$, so I assume you define it to be $0$ by continuity ?

Comment: And what is your question actually ? What does this picture has to do with the limit that you want to compute ?

Comment: Question is "How to apply L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate limit at $x=a$ for $ \frac {f(x,a)-f(a,x)}{(x-a)} $ which has $\frac00$ form? If it cannot be applied, how is the limit found?"

Comment: The blue curve has a zero value for the required limit in a particular cited case at $ x=e. $ We are now trying to establish an analytical  procedure to evaluate it.

Comment: We have limit value $0$, not $e^e$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: add $f(a,a)$ and subtract $f(a,a)$ in the nominator. Then see the partial derivatives that form. You get $\partial_1f(a,a)-\partial_2 f(a,a)$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x,a)-f(a,a)-(f(a,x)-f(a,a))}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x,a)-f(a,a)}{x-a}-\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(a,x)-f(a,a)}{x-a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a,a)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(a,a) $$

**Example:** 
If $f(x,e)=x^e$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=ex^{e-1}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial e}=x^e \ln(x)$. Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{x\to e}{\frac{x^e-e^x}{x-e}} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(e,e)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial e}(e,e)=e\cdot e^{e-1}-e^e\ln e=0$$

**Remark:** As you have the particular type of the function $f(x,a)$ you can already apply L'Hospital's rule also:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to e}{\frac{x^e-e^x}{x-e}} =\lim\limits_{x\to e}{\frac{(x^e-e^x)'}{(x-e)'}}=\lim\limits_{x\to e}{\frac{ex^{e-1}-e^x}{1}}=0$$
**L'Hospital's rule**, can be applied as follows to the original problem: if you denote $\varphi(x)=f(x,a)$ and $\psi(x)=f(a,x)$ you have in the nominator $(\varphi(x)-\psi(x))'_{|x=a}=\varphi'(x)_{|x=a}-\psi'(x)_{|x=a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a,a)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(a,a)$

Comment: Not clear, like this next?
$$ \frac {(f(x,a)-f(a,a))- (f(a,x)-f(a,a))}{(x-a)} $$

Comment: Yes, this is how you continue !

Comment: If I take $ x^e$, then  $ e x ^{e-1} - e^ x$ evaluated at $ x= e \rightarrow  $   $  e  e^{e-1} - e^e = 0$ *always* , right?

Comment: No, if $f(x,y)=x^e$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=ex^{e-1}$, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=0$. Here the derivative with respect to the first argument is denoted by $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}$ and with respect to the second variable is denoted by $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}$. Therefore the limit would be $ex^{e-1}-0$ evaluated at $x=e$. This makes $e^e$

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: Not at all clear how it plots to $0$ when you say it should be $e^e.$

Comment: Aha, I understand. My previous comment was not correct. If $f(x,e)=x^e$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=ex^{e-1}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial e}=x^e \ln(x)$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(e,e)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial e}(e,e)=e\cdot e^{e-1}-e^e\ln e=0$

Comment: Thank you very much , now it is quite clear and settled. To the moderator: The discussion has now come to a proper close, Thanks