# Find slope at tangent line.

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Ok, so this question is a bit odd: it is asking for the slope of the tangent line to the function

$$x^y = y^x$$

at the points $(c,c)$. Yeah, the variable is $c$, I'm somewhat confused. I plugged in to the implicitly derived function

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(y-x\ln(y))}{x(x-y\ln(x)}$$

and got this

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{c(c-c\ln(c))}{c(c-c\ln(c)}$$

I'm not sure if I'm overthinking it and the answer is simply **1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lot more context here, but you are correct in that if you plug $(x,y) = (c,c)$ into that equation you get $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$, or equivalently $y=x$

Comment: yeah i just wasnt sure if that would simply be the answer or not and regards to the context what am i missing? I can vouch for the derivative to be right.

Comment: @CarlosV Since you just posted about differentiating $x^y = y^x$ I was under the assumption that this was your context, although this answer is still conditional still upon the domain of $c$... I assumed both are $ > 0$, as this answer is wildly different otherwise

Comment: I have another question hoping you can answer how would i determine at what points would make the tangent line not exist?

Comment: @CarlosV to start, $\log(0)$ is undefined, so if $c=0$ the tangent line is undefined. If you are ignoring complex numbers then the tangent line doesn't necessarily exist for $c<0$ either, although this is heavily conditional.

Comment: Would that still qualify for the derivative? $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(y-x\ln(y))}{x(x-y\ln(x))}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "qualify" here. I specified that $c=0$ in my comment, and the derivative does not have a $c$ in it (as $x$ and $y$ can differ). Do you mind elaborating on what you mean? It is true that the derivative is undefined if either $x=0$ or $y=0$, although the limit of the derivative as $x \to 0$ exists (and analogously $y \to 0$), as (as $\lim {x \to 0} [\log(x)]= -\infty$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29329/discussion-between-carlos-v-and-brevan-ellefsen).

Comment: @CarlosV: That is a good derivative. But only at those points where the implicit function theorem can be applied. For example that formula gives you the slope of the tangent to the curve at $(x,y)=(2,4)$. But you get $0/0$ at $(x,y)=(e,e)$. The implicit function theorem does not guarantee you a tangent at that point, and the geometric reason for that is apparent from PM 2Ring's answer below - two branches meet there.

Comment: Slope $dy/dx$ at (0,0) and (e,e) appears be zero, in the immediate neighborhood of (e,e). Verified by plot below also.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $x^y = y^x$ is a bit funny, as you can see from the graph, which looks roughly like a hyperbola, with the line $y=x$ added to it. The line crosses the "hyperbola" where $y=x=e$, so the derivative at that point is not well-defined.

[image: graph of x^y = y^x]]

(Graph courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5Ey+%3D+y%5Ex))

Clearly, for any *other* point $(c,c)$, i.e., points where $c \ne e$, the slope of the tangent to $x^y = y^x$ at $(c,c)$ is simply the slope of the line $y=x$, which is 1.

---

I suppose I ought to mention that if we remove the $y=x$ part and approach $(e, e)$ along the "hyperbolic" branch of $x^y = y^x$ the derivative approaches -1.

FWIW, although $x^y = y^x$ can't be expressed explicitly using elementary functions, it *can* be using the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function: 
$$y=\exp \left( -W \left( \frac{-\ln x}{x} \right) \right)$$

Also, it's easy to generate solution pairs $(x,y)$ of $x^y = y^x$ by this simple parametrization:

Let $y = ux$

$$\begin{align}
x^y & = y^x\\
x^{ux} & = y^x\\
x^{u} & = y = ux\\
x^{u-1} & = u\\
x & = u^\frac{1}{u-1}\\
y & = u^\frac{u}{u-1}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: The hyperbola like curve is near to hyperbola $ x y = e^2$

Comment: @Narasimham: Indeed. Let $u=1+\frac{1}{n}$ in the parametrization. Then $x=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n, \, y=(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$, so $x$ & $y$ approach $e$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, i.e., as $u \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Is it not possible to get this directly as y = f(x) ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice, logarithms is defined for positive real numbers only hence you need to give a condition of arbitrary constant $\color{red}{c>0}$ otherwise log will be undefined.

Moreover the slope will be undefined in form of $\frac{0}{0}$ at $c=e$ so we should have another condition $\color{red}{c\neq e}$

Now, we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(y-x\ln(y))}{x(x-y\ln(x))}$$

Now, the slope of the tangent at the given point $(c, c)$ is $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(x=c, \ y=c)}=\frac{c(c-c\ln(c))}{c(c-c\ln(c))}=1$$

so your answer is correct (given additional conditions $\color{red}{c>0, \ c\neq e}$).

Comment: oops yeah i forgot about that.

Comment: This is not true. Logarithms can be defined for negative numbers easily, and even complex numbers. You just either get 1 or infinite solutions, unless you make a branch cut.

Comment: Alright, if you are right then $\ln(-2)=$? & $\ln(2+i3)=$?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Assuming the standard branch cut, $\log(-2) = \log(2) + \pi i$, and $\log(2+3i)$ is a transcendental number (i.e., it can't be simplified further, but is $\approx$ $1.28i$)

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Actually, you can write $\log(2+3i)$ as $\frac{\log(13)}{2}+i \tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{2})$ if you want, but this isn't really any simpler

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: Technically you're right, but surely in the context of this problem we are restricted to real $x,y$ (necessarily positive for the power functions to be well defined). Thus I fail to see the point of bringing up complex logarithms here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main issue here is  whether the fraction can always be simplified.

Clearly, for $c\neq e, 0$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$.

So for continuous function $f(x)$, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ approaches to $1$ from both side at $x=e$.

Similar for $x=0$.

Comment: You bring up an interesting point here that $c$ is undefined for $c=e$. Good catch!

Comment: We may perhaps need to find a limiting function  $ \frac{x^y-y^x}{x-y} $ as $ x \rightarrow y$. I asked a doubt here related to this couple of days ago.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439390/limit-of-function-formed-by-taking-difference-after-swapping-a-variable-consta

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If we attempt to find solution for $ e^x = x^e $ we have a second real root in addition to the obvious $ x= e$.

Similarly $ x^y = y^x $ contains another real function other than the obvious $ x= y, $ that should be isolated.

[image: $ dy/dx for x^y-y^x $]